# Uninitialised Constant Iconv

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Recently was advised to used the following code in order to avoid UTF-8 problems with input text into a database.

```
ic = Iconv.new('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8')
#valid_string = ic.iconv(untrusted_string + ' ')[0..-2]
row[4] = ic.iconv(row[4] + ' ')[0..-2]
row[5] = ic.iconv(row[5] + ' ')[0..-2]
```

In development this works perfectly, however, once pushed onto our server we get the problem "uninitialised constant iconv" when we try to run the rake file containing the above code.

Is there an easy way to fix this issue?  Tried adding `gem 'iconv'` to the gem file and running bundle install  but this produced loads of errors, so assuming this is not the correct way to fix it...

Comment: Fixed it by adding `require 'iconv'` at the top of the rake file

Comment: You can add your answer and accept it if you wish.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Fixed it by adding require 'iconv' at the top of the rake file